# why SQL server studio query not found?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, jobs

I am new on this and tried to create a query in SSMS 2014. The results I wanted to be send to my email in a body and not as a file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFMBb.png)

First I made a very simple query. I saved the query in a folder C:\Users\XXX\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Custom Reports\qry_bank. How ever I could not find this file in the object explorer.

Then I made a job (T-SQL)

```
use [001]
go

SELECT [BankAccount]
 FROM [dbo].[BankAccountsView]
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'sql mail profile',  
    @recipients = 'XXXXXXXXXX',  
 @subject = 'Memory Values',
@query = 'qry_Bank',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
```

The questions is how can I select my query in this code?

Comment: Object Explorer is not a file-system explorer.

Comment: Ok I now but how can I use my query in this job an execute this?

Comment: Convert your query to a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Hi ok how do I do this?